# Check date in controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method in controller that receives a parameter like this:

```
def example
   .... 
   params[:Date]
end
```

And I just want to validate if the date is not of yesterday or earlier.

This date is not entered in the database, then the validation is required to be made ​​in the controller and not in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def example
  unless Date.strptime(params[:date], '%d/%m/%Y').before? Date.today.beginning_of_day
    #did not happen yesterday or before
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a params[:at] that looks like this:

```
params[:at]
=> "05-10-2012"
```

Which I parse like this:

```
date = Date.strptime(params[:at], "%m-%d-%Y")
```

If I'd like to check if it's not yesterday or earlier I'd go:

```
date > Date.today.beginning_of_day
```

But this is Rails syntax, since they've added helper methods to base classes.

What does you params[:Date] look like? Is this Rails or plain Ruby?